# Child div is outside of the parent one?

Tags: html, css

I see that when we use table + tr + td we never see inner elements outside of outer elements.

But in case of Divs it can be. 
Now I see that my inner div is located outside of parent div.
How to control child divs? What is wrong in my html?

I mean I have next html and I see that child div is outside of the parent

```
<div id="page">
        <div  id="main">

          <div id="djInfo">
           </div>

           <div id="footer">

           </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    #page
    {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        height: 100%;  
        position: relative;
    }

    #main
    {    
        padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        background-color: #0c1114;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        _height: 1px;  /*only IE6 applies CSS properties starting with an underscore */ 
         text-align: center;  
         height: 100%;    
         position: relative;
    }

    #footer
    {
        color: #999;
        padding: 0px 0;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: normal;
        margin: 0;
        font-size: .9em;
        background-image: url('img/BottomGradient.jpg');
        background-repeat:repeat;   
        height: 160px;   
        width: 100%;  
        float: left; 
    }

#djInfo
{ 
    float: left; 
    position: relative;   
    margin-left: 250px;  

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I kinda constructed what you posted and everything seems to work fine?

http://jsfiddle.net/XrDTe/

But please, double check your code, there are some redundancies in it.

(Why give something with 100% width margin-left/right: auto? Why all the float: left's and the position: relative's? Why the IE6 height of 1px?  All of this is not necessary and may hinder you in writing decent, to-the-point CSS)